# How would I make a command toggling command server specific

Tags: discord.py

I'm pretty new to coding in Python and I'm starting to make a Discord bot. I've made a command that will toggle on and off commands but I can't seem to figure out how to make it server specific. Meaning if the admin of a server with my bot toggles off a command it will only toggle off on their server and not everyone else's. Any help would be great thanks.

**My Code:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def toggle(ctx, *, command):
    command = client.get_command(command)
    if command == None:
        elk = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), title=f"I can't find a command with that name!")
        await ctx.send(embed=elk)

    elif ctx.command == command:
        psos = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), title=f"You cannot disable this command!")
        await ctx.send(embed=psos)

    else:
        command.enabled = not command.enabled
        ternary = "enabled" if command.enabled else "disabled"
        lllj = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.dark_gold(), title=f"I have {ternary} {command.qualified.name} for you!")
        await ctx.send(embed=lllj)
```

Comment: You will need to use a database or something to store the settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Discord documentation about registering a command](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#registering-a-command):

> Commands can be scoped either globally or to a specific guild. Global commands are available for every guild that adds your app.

A guild is defined by the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-resource) as:

> Guilds in Discord represent an isolated collection of users and channels, and are often referred to as "servers" in the UI.

I'm not sure this fully answer your question, if this is not the case I suggest you an in depth reading of the [official developer documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro).